# postgresql: how to use a particular database

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am quite new to postgresql and I am looking to timprove.  I mostly use MySQL and from what I see already there are a few differences.  Under mysql i would want to use or change my database (d1), i simply say the command

```
use d1;
```

What do I do under postgres?

I can view the databases and roles using commands such as:

```
select * from pg_roles;
select datname from pg_database;
```

Also are there comprehensive online resouces that I can point to?

Thanks

Comment: You specify the database when connecting: `psql -d d1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Psql uses short commands prefixed by a backslash to identify **'meta-commmands'**; inputs that are for the command shell and not commands to be sent to the database.

You can get a list of these by typing `\?`

You can change databases in psql by using `\c databasename`

Here's the [psql documentation for the newest release](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-psql.html)